# Keeping UITableView and UICollectionView scroll position in sync

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UIViewController` that is able to show its content via a `UICollectionView` (cv) or via a`UITableView` (tv).

Both views are added to the view hierarchy via storyboard and I'm just hiding the one that should not be shown. Both the `UICollectionView` and the `UITableView` have the same data source.
The `UICollectionView` is showing the content in a two items per row grid, the `UITableView` obviously in a one item per row grid.

So what I want to happen is if the user decides to switch between the views the newly shown view should scroll to the element that was visible in the other view.

I did some experimenting with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` and `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` with no success.

I understand, that both the `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` are able to return their current visible items'/rows' indexPaths, but how can i transform those indexPath to a indexPath of the other view and tell them to scroll to that element?

My current touch event handling of the switch button looks like this:

```html
- (IBAction)switchView:(id)sender {
    
    self.showListView = !self.showListView;
    
    UIView *fromView, *toView;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    
    if (self.showListView)
    {
        fromView = self.ArticleCollection;
        toView = self.ArticleList;
        
        CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.ArticleCollection.contentOffset, .size = self.ArticleCollection.bounds.size};
        CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(100, CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
        indexPath = [self.ArticleCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];
    }
    else
    {
        fromView = self.ArticleList;
        toView = self.ArticleCollection;
        
        CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.ArticleList.contentOffset, .size = self.ArticleList.bounds.size};
        CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(100, CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
        indexPath = [self.ArticleList indexPathForRowAtPoint:visiblePoint];
    }
    
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    
    if (self.showListView) {
        [self.ArticleList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row*2 inSection:0]
                                atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                        animated:NO];
    } else {
        [self.ArticleCollection scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:ceil(row/2)
                                                                            inSection:0
                                                                     atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
                                                                             animated:NO]];
    }
    
    // Here a transitionFromView:ToView:duration:options:completion call follows
}
```

Thanks in advance for any contribution to my problem.

Comment: Why don't you simple use the `UICollectionView` and just switch Flow layouts to change between single and double column mode ?

Comment: Good question. I didn't think about that solution, yet. But I guess the layout switch would cause the single cell layout to break since the cv is showing an image with text below that image and the tv the image on the left and the text on its right hand side.

Comment: You can create different collection view cell layouts as well and when you switch mode you provide the different cell layout.

Comment: If you do what I'm suggesting you get also the automatic flow layout switch animation for free :)

Comment: Well, that sounds like a good solution to optimize my current implementation. I will at least try your approach. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appart from a little typo inside the *scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:* call:

```
[self.ArticleCollection scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row
                                                                        inSection:0]
                                                                 atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
                                                                         animated:NO];
```

I did think *indexPath.row* would hold different values whether it came from the cv's visible indexPath or the tv's visible indexPath so I calculated the new row by multiplying or dividing through 2. But as it turns out the rows are identical in both cases, so I just needed to use the same value for both cases:

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

if (self.showListView) {
    [self.ArticleList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]
                            atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                    animated:NO];
} else {
    [self.ArticleCollection scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row
                                                                        inSection:0]
                                                                 atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
                                                                         animated:NO];
}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.